# Can't remove � symbols in R with regex

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to clean text data before doing operations with it and the � symbol keeps not getting removed even when I try to target it specifically with gsub and then throwing an error when I try to lower cases.

```
normalize_name <- function(name){
  
  normalized_name <- gsub("[^[0-9A-Za-z][:blank:]]", "", name) #Removes special characters and spaces
  normalized_name <- gsub("�", "", normalized_name)
  normalized_name <- tolower(normalized_name)
  return(normalized_name)
}
```

Comment: Instead of removing such symbols, you should fix the way you obtain the data, here, most probably, the encoding of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
normalize_name <- function(name){
  
  normalized_name <- gsub("[^[0-9A-Za-z][:blank:]]", "", name) #Removes special characters and spaces
  normalized_name <- gsub("\UFFFD", "", normalized_name)
  normalized_name <- tolower(normalized_name)
  return(normalized_name)
}
```